# Удаляется ли база данных после скачивания обновлений на андроид с Play Market?

Tags: java, android, playmarket

Подскажите, удаляется ли база данных или вообще с ней что то происходит после принятия обновлений с плей маркета на андроиде? И какие вообще лучше принять действия при разработке что бы исключить такие моменты?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Само по себе обновление на БД никак не влияет. БД это просто файл в папке который читается кодом приложения.

Если в приложении в коде подразумеваются изменения в БД, то надо написать скрипты миграции схемы БД которые приложение выполнит при первом старте после обновления.

По сути обновление из магазина ничем не отличается от перезапуска оного же из студии.

Comment: то есть когда юзер принимает обновления, то приложение не сносится, а потом не стаивтся заново, и по этому база данных остается, она снесется только в том случае, если будет как то изменена БД, и из за этого она переустановится, верно?

Comment: @MainStar, нет, приложение при обновлении удаляется и ставится заново. Однако БазаДанных, если она создана стандартным кодом в приложении (а не поставляется в готовом виде вместе с приложением) записывается в специальную папку для файлов приложения и не удаляется при удалении приложения при обновлении. В случае обновления приложения файл с БД в этом случае никак не трогается.

Comment: окей, а что если нужно что бы были таблицы со статически забитыми данными, тогда под это лучше сделать отдельную БД, которая будет передаваться каждый раз при получении обновлений и отдельную базу данных для юзеров, которая будет создаваться внутри приложения, верно?

Comment: Тут можно по разному. Можно 2 разные БД, можно данные в виде JSON в assets положить и из него одну БД наполнять. Тут универсального решения нет. Однако 2 БД будет сложно поддерживать, лучше одну иметь. Также сложнее поставлять приложение с готовой БД. Так что я бы выбрал отдельный файл с данными и заполнение БД этими данными программно.

Comment: понял, спаисбо!